# "Schematic Claim"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, context

I would like to know what does "schematic claim" in the following encrypt mean which is from an [entry](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/feminist-philosophy/) of Standford Encyclopedia of Philosophy:

> To consider some of the different strategies for responding to the
>   phenomenon of intersectionality, let’s return to the **schematic
>   claims** that women are oppressed and this oppression is wrong or
>   unjust.

Comment: It means - A sketchy/incomplete assertion that something is true. In this case, a sketchy/incomplete assertion that women are oppressed.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because identifying the sense intended requires analysis of much context: it's a 'comprehension' exercise, only useful to other readers of the actual reference work.

Comment: I have no idea what *the following* ***encrypt*** means in this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of context, the meaning of "schematic claims" is unclear.  But when you look at the whole article, the meaning of this statement is fairly unambiguous.

At the end of section 2.1, "Feminist Beliefs and Feminist Movements," the author writes,

> Given the controversies over the term and the politics of circumscribing the boundaries of a social movement, it is sometimes tempting to think that the best we can do is to articulate a set of disjuncts that capture a range of feminist beliefs. However, at the same time it can be both intellectually and politically valuable to have a **schematic** framework that enables us to map at least some of our points of agreement and disagreement.

([Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/feminist-philosophy/), emphasis added)

In section 2.2., we find "In an effort to suggest a **schematic** account of feminism, Susan James characterizes feminism as follows..." (emphasis added)

Finally, in 2.3 (in addition to the portion quoted in the question), we read,

> Following [bell] hooks’ lead, we might characterize feminism **schematically** (allowing the **schema** to be filled in differently by different accounts) as the view that women are subject to sexist oppression and that this is wrong.

Thus, in this context, it appears that "schematic claims" are claims related to, or which are a part of the schematic framework of feminism that the author is creating.

Comment: Thanks for analyzing the different parts of the piece to illuminate the meaning, intended by the writer!

Comment: Just to be more clear, I would like to say:

If we replate "schematic" by "systematic", it would retain the same sense. Right?

Comment: Yes, @MushrrafBaigAshraf *systematic* would be a pretty good substitute.